# What is the meaning of the function arguments like "(url[, data[, proxies[, context]]])"?

Tags: python

For example, when I am reading the Python standard library documentation, I got the [`urlopen` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen), and I do not understand the meaning of the format like:

```
urllib.urlopen(url[, data[, proxies[, context]]])
```

What does the arguments' format mean?

Comment: `[, data[, proxies[, context]]]` means that  `data`, `proxies` and `context` are optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets denote *optional arguments*. The function takes at least a `url` argument, with `data`, `proxies` and `context` being optional.

The notation is somewhat misleading. You can pass in a `proxies` argument without providing a `data` argument, if you use it as a keyword argument, for example. The [actual function signature](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c2bba3c9424b/Lib/urllib.py#l72) is:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, proxies=None, context=None):
```

so `url` is *required*` the other arguments can either be passed in as positional arguments or keyword arguments.